# How to show a line in a Manipulate plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

I'm trying to display a Graphics line alongside my Manipulate plot but I can't seem to do it because the Graphics and the Plot do not show up together.

Basically, I want to show this line

```
Graphics[{Dashed,Line[{{0,2974.83},{10,2974.83}}]}]
```

inside my `Manipulate` `Plot` where my `Plot` will be interactive and the line will also be there.

Here is my `Manipulate` `Plot` if that is helpful:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[((5949.66-(0.669207*(471-bd)+0.068928*(bd)))/-10*t+5949.66),{t,0,10},
    AxesLabel->{"years from now", "billion Kg CO2eq"},
    PlotRange->All],
    {{bd,0,"Beef (dairy herd) factories converted"},0,417}
    ]
```

I have attached a picture of what I would want it to look like.[image]

I am pretty new to the software so any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I have mixed up something or need to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: see the examples in  [Show](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) and  in [Epilog](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

Comment: see also [GridLines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html)

Comment: `Epilog -> {Dashed, 
  Line[{{0, 2974.83}, {10, 2974.83}}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `GridLines` to the `Plot` and a `Control` to move it up and down:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  ((5949.66 - (0.669207*(471 - bd) + 0.068928*(bd)))/-10*t + 
    5949.66),
  {t, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {"years from now", "billion Kg CO2eq"},
  PlotRange -> All,
  GridLines -> {None, {{gl, Dashed}}}
  ],
 
 {{bd, 0, "Beef (dairy herd) factories converted"}, 0, 417},
 {{gl, 1000, "GridLine"}, 500, 6000}
 ]
```

[image]